# Purpose of this Zener diode (reverse protection)

Tags: mosfet, diodes, zener, reverse-polarity

I have the below MOSFET circuit:

[image]

Zener diode - [Datasheet](https://www.nexperia.com/products/diodes/automotive-diodes/automotive-zener-diodes/BZX84-C12.html)

N-channel MOSFET - [Datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BUK7Y3R5-40E.pdf)

I want to understand what is the purpose of the Zener diode D5202 and at what conditions does the Zener diode come into action?

Comment: It appears to be a do-nothing-other-than-get-hot circuit and the power rails are undefined on the drain so, there's nothing much to add. There is every chance that this circuit doesn't actually do anything useful.

Comment: Suppose the 9-16V rail goes negative at different times? At that time, does it help?

Comment: I can't see the purpose of analysing this circuit because it isn't self-evident what it does. The zener is to protect the gate from getting too much voltage BTW (if the supply voltages were appropriate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to understand what is the purpose of the Zener diode D5202 and
> at what conditions does the Zener diode come into action?*

If this were your circuit: -

[image]

Then you could say with a certain amount of authority that the zener diode prevents the gate-source from being over-driven by an excessive voltage fed in to the right side of the 10 kohm resistor. It's quite common practice to do this.